# Creating a wallet and account

Tags: wallets, nethereum, keystore, .net

I am using nethereum, and am creating an account. But I believe it is better to create the wallet first. I then save the account to a keystore:

```
Wallet wallet = new Wallet(Wordlist.English, WordCount.Twelve);
string words = string.Join(" ", wallet.Words);
byte[] privateKey = wallet.GetPrivateKey(0); //a wallet can have many accounts
string address = wallet.GetAddresses()[0];
KeyStoreScryptService keyStoreService = new KeyStoreScryptService();

var keyStore = keyStoreService.EncryptAndGenerateKeyStore(password, privateKey, address);
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I am doing this?

Comment: I think you have to setup a wallet address first manually.
Metamask for example. There are plenty of tutorials on youtube how to go about it.